# Is it possible to apply different types to a generic based on the polymorph?

Tags: c#

I had a look at similar  questions, but none seemed to getting at exactly what I was attempting, I'm not sure if this is related to covariance in generics which a read a little on in the .NET docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Here is what I am trying to achieve, I have two families of  classes, but an inherited queue that I want to handle a different type depending on the class its in, although a lot of the logic will be similar apart from 1 or 2 class specific things:

```
abstract class foo
{
     protected Queue<base> myQueue;
}

class bar:foo
{
    //something to allow me to use myQueue as a Queue<derived>
}
```

It's my first question on here, so sorry for any missing etiquette and thanks in advance!

Comment: If you paramaterise `foo` and `bar` on the type of the item inside the queue (e.g. `class Foo<T> { Queue<T> myQueue; }`) then you might be able to get somewhere using [type constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) to enforce the items are subclasses (but it's been a while since I've C#'d so not sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a generic type parameter and assign the derived class to it:

```
abstract class foo<T> where T: foo<T>
{
    protected Queue<T> myQueue;
}

class bar: foo<bar>
{
   
}
```

The `where T: foo<T>` makes sure that only the base class and all classes derived from it are allowed to be assigned

you could then also continue this pattern if you want to derive further from it:

```
class bar<T>: foo<T> where T: bar<T>
{
    
}
```

This makes sure that if you use your queue inside of that derived class, the type is at least `bar<T>`, with everything (methods, props..) available to it.

Comment: I didnt realise you could specify the generic that you inherit from, that's awesome, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what it is exactly that you want to achieve, but this may help.

Seems like you want to make myQueue generic, you cant do that using this approach.

```
public abstract class Foo<T> where T : class
{
    protected Queue<T> myQueue;
}

public class Bar : Foo<SomeType>
{

}

public class SomeType
{

}
```

For example, code above has Bar class which inherits from Foo class, which has a generic parameter T. In this instance, SomeType is used for this generic parameter. Therefore class Bar has member myQueue of type Queue.

Comment: so myQueue is a Queue<SomeType> in Foo?

Comment: In my example, yes. With this approach, you could make myQueue of type Queue<SomeOtherType> or Queue<Bar>, ... Your using the generic Queue so you can store any type of object there.

Btw, the keyword here is generics, that's what you need to learn here.

Comment: I didnt realise you could specify the generic that you inherit from, that's awesome, thanks

Comment: thanks also to you, your answer was the same as accepted but my SO says that was first by a smidgen