# Making arrays to hold polymorphed generics

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, data-structures

The question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925080/is-it-possible-to-apply-different-types-to-a-generic-based-on-the-polymorph) brought me thus far on my project:

```
abstract class Base<T> where T:ContentBase
{
    //base functionality
}

class Foo : Base<FooContent>
{
    //overrides
}

class Bar : Base<BarContent>
{
    //overrides
}
```

Is there a way to make an array or List that can hold both Foo and Bar objects or would I have to look at making a record or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could add a non-generic abstract class `Base` that `Base<T>` inherits from, and then make a `List<Base>`

Comment: _"Is there a way to make an array or List that can hold both `Foo` and `Bar` objects"_ - have you considered using a union-type instead?

Comment: @Luke could you submit that as an answer? That's what I was looking for :)

Comment: @DanielFamakin absolutely, answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a non-generic abstract class `Base` that `Base<T>` inherits from, and then make a `List<Base>`. So extending your code might look something like this:

```cs
abstract class Base 
{
    //base functionality (non-generic)
}

abstract class Base<T> : Base where T : ContentBase
{
    //base functionality acting on T
}

class Foo : Base<FooContent>
{
    //overrides
}

class Bar : Base<BarContent>
{
    //overrides
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming from the example code that `FooContent` and `BarContent` derive from `ContentBase`. I'm also assuming that the code follows the SOLID principles and especially LSP.

A generic collection could be defined in terms of `ContentBase`.

```
var collection = new List<ContentBase>();
```

The collection can hold instances of `FooContent`, `BarContent`, and `ContentBase`.

---

But apparently that is a need to hold the `ContentBase` and derived types within another type. (It is not clear from the question why this is needed.)

```
public class ContentAdaptor
{
    public ContentAdaptor(ContentBase content)
    {
        _content = content;
    }

    ...

    private ContentBase _content;
}
```

The `ContentAdaptor` type holds a reference to an instance of `ContentBase`. The instance could be of a derived type.

A collection of `ContentAdaptor`:

```
var collection = new List<ContentAdaptor>();
```

---

I have a suspicion that `FooContent` and `BarContent` may violate LSP and are not substitutable for each other. Is that the case? If you have types that are fundamentally different but you want to process the objects in a polymorphic way, consider an interface.

```
public interface IProcess
{
    bool Process();
}
```

Here `ContentBase` implements the `IProcess` interface. But note that a `SomeOtherContent` type that doesn't derive from `ContentBase` can also implement the `IProcess` interface.

```
public class ContentBase : IProcess
{
    // Implement the IProcess interface.
}
```

A collection of `IProcess`:

```
var collection = new List<IProcess>();
```

The `Process` method can be called on each object in the collection. Each type provides its own implementation of the `Process` method.

Comment: According to my brief research LSP states that classes should be substitutable for their bases, not for one another.

That said as far as my code works now content classes all have the data needed to adapt their functionality within their call sites, so I think LSP is intact and an interface isn't necessary here. Correct me if i'm wrong, however.

Comment: Yes, sub-types should be substitutable for the base type. That means that two sub-types are substitutable for each other when they are treated as being of the base type. Sub-types can't remove or change the semantics of methods that the base type provides. I was giving a shortened version of that instead of fully explaining.